# Mysql query to count result by removing time from datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to write one query in which i need to fetch/count records which are registered on same date. But the issue is that in mysql structure created_date field have "datetime" structure.

Let me give you example

If 5 people are registered on 2015-02-25 and 6 people registered on 2015-02-11. It will output as

```
Sno. Date.           count
1)   2015-02-25        5  
2)   2015-02-11        6
```

Here is sample of attached database rows for better understanding
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPeLl.png

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: `date(created_at)` will give you the date only in your query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date(created_at),count(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

your query should be like this:

```
select date(created_at) created_at, count(*) from TABLE 
    group by date(created_at)
```

Select between dates

```
select date(created_at) created_at, count(*) from TABLE 
    where date(created_at) >= '2015-02-11' and date(created_at) <= '2015-02-25' 
    group by date(created_at)
```

With [between](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

```
select date(created_at) created_at, count(*) from Mytable  
   where date(created_at) BETWEEN '2015-01-05' AND '2015-02-25' 
   group by date(created_at)
```

Referrence: [count()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)

Comment: what if i need to count data between two dates via date picker. Please help me

Comment: @AnilSingh use `where` before group by

Comment: I tried this query select date(created_at) created_at, count(*) from Mytable where created_at BETWEEN '2015-02-25' AND '2015-01-05' group by date(created_at)
but it gives me empty result

Comment: @AnilSingh before posting your question, you should show what you have tried or what error you get and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AnilSingh it should be `select date(created_at) created_at, count(*) from Mytable where date(created_at) BETWEEN '2015-02-25' AND '2015-01-05' group by date(created_at)`

Comment: It still gives me empty result
 select date(created_at) created_at, count(*) from Mytable where date(created_at) BETWEEN '2015-02-25' AND '2015-01-05' group by date(created_at)

Comment: Sure i'll but i don't have reputation now :(

Answer (score 0):

```
It might be the one that you expected.

SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d") AS Date,
COUNT(*) AS count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d")
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

This query will count the registered people in each day. Of course the latest registration will come first.